# What value is returned in a grid search score?

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, grid-search

I ran a `GridSearchCV` on a prediction model with scoring set to accuracy. `X` and `Y` are the test splits.

```
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV 
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
from sklearn.svm import SVC

tuned_parameters = [{'kernel': ['rbf'], 'gamma': [1e-3, 1e-4],
                 'C': [10, 100, 1000]}]


print("Tuning hyperparameters for accuracy")

clf_gs = GridSearchCV(SVC(), tuned_parameters, cv=5,
               scoring = 'accuracy')
clf_gs.fit(X, Y)

print(clf_gs.best_params_)

print("Grid scores on development set:")

means = clf_gs.cv_results_['mean_test_score']
stds = clf_gs.cv_results_['std_test_score']
for mean, std, params in zip(means, stds, clf_gs.cv_results_['params']):
    print("%0.3f (+/-%0.03f) for %r"
          % (mean, std * 2, params))

print("The scores are computed on the full evaluation set.")

y_true, y_pred = Y, clf_gs.predict(X)
print(classification_report(y_true, y_pred))
```

I got the grid scores as

```
Tuning hyperparameters for accuracy

{'C': 1000, 'gamma': 0.001, 'kernel': 'rbf'}

Grid scores on development set:

0.994 (+/-0.000) for {'C': 10, 'gamma': 0.001, 'kernel': 'rbf'}
0.986 (+/-0.000) for {'C': 10, 'gamma': 0.0001, 'kernel': 'rbf'}
0.995 (+/-0.001) for {'C': 100, 'gamma': 0.001, 'kernel': 'rbf'}
0.988 (+/-0.000) for {'C': 100, 'gamma': 0.0001, 'kernel': 'rbf'}
0.995 (+/-0.001) for {'C': 1000, 'gamma': 0.001, 'kernel': 'rbf'}
0.994 (+/-0.001) for {'C': 1000, 'gamma': 0.0001, 'kernel': 'rbf'}


The scores are computed on the full evaluation set.
              precision    recall  f1-score   support

           0       1.00      1.00      1.00     67343
           3       0.88      0.78      0.83       995

    accuracy                           1.00     68338
   macro avg       0.94      0.89      0.91     68338
weighted avg       1.00      1.00      1.00     68338
```

`sklearn.metrics.GridSearchCV.score` says it returns the score of the given data. Is it the accuracy score of the prediction model or a different score related to `GridSearchCV`? I am just confused as I got above 99% score here when I only got below 90% accuracy with parameter values set to default using `SVC` and didn't expect to see this much improvement.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, according to this line of code:

```
clf_gs = GridSearchCV(SVC(), tuned_parameters, cv=5,
               scoring = 'accuracy')
```

, your scoring metric is `accuracy`.

The difference between `CV`/`eval` scores comes from the data set: `CV` is trained and tested on the 5-fold cross validation sets, which are subsets of your training data. In contrast, `eval` is trained on the whole training data, and tested on the test data, which is independent of your training set.

You can google **'k-fold cross-validation washinton'** to see more detail on the underlying algorithms.

Comment: I think it returns a score based on the best accuracy value that can be obtained and not necessarily the actual accuracy value that can be obtained. Because I tuned the values of **C**  and **gamma** to 1000 and 0.001 respectively but didn't get that high an accuracy. I still have my doubts but thanks for answering.

Comment: Or take a look at [this thread on Kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/c/mercedes-benz-greener-manufacturing/discussion/34471), maybe the problem came from the property of your data.